# Android Tabs - Navigation between tabs causing memory leak

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-sdk-2.3

I finished an application recently and began profiling it for CPU & Memory usage and came across a memory leak:

In a simple 3 tab application where each tab has a distinct function, I have a button on Tab3 which sends the user back to Tab1 along with a messageId. The activity associated with Tab1 catches this extra and displays the message if its present. See below for the button in Tab3:

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TabContainerActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.setAction("com.test.notify.MESSAGE");
    notificationIntent.putExtra(MessageBean.MESSAGE_ID, messageId);
    startActivity(notificationIntent);
}
```

The tab container `TabContainerActivity.class` replicates `Extras` to child Actions. It also has logic to capture the `Action` sent with the intent and if one is found, it is used to decide which tab to set as current:

```
if(getIntent().getExtras() != null ) intent.putExtras(getIntent().getExtras());
if(getIntent().getAction().equalsIgnoreCase("com.test.notify.MESSAGE"))
{       
    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
}
else if(getIntent().getAction().equalsIgnoreCase("com.test.notify.SETTINGS"))
{
    tabHost.setCurrentTab(1);
}
...etc...
```

With the above code you can move between Tabs normally, you can also click on a message in Tab3 and have it displayed in full in Tab1 - Great! The code can easily be modified in future to allow other applications to pass MessageID's to the first tabs activity, Wonderfu!

However - This behaviour is now in evidence:

1. Click Tab3,
2. Select a message
   [[ A new intent is sent, opening a new `TabContainerActivity` activity]]
3. Inside this activity click Tab3,
4. Select another message
   [[ A new intent is sent, opening ANOTHER new `TabContainerActivity` activity]]
5. (Repeat 3 & 4 & 5)

Hopefully you can see the problem! You can go `back` through each of these activities, pealing them off the stack, but because of the recursive nature of the problem you can continue navigating, creating a new activity with each pass, to the point of OutOfMemory exceptions.

So, to the question;

I want the functionality contained inside Tab1's activity to run whenever the Tab is made visible (In this case, loading a message) so I would like to keep it as an Activity in its own right. Saying that, when navigated to I want it to be the only Tab Activity which is on the stack. How can I achieve this?

Any help and discussion would be appreciated!

Comment: you mean you want that if a tab is previously shown it would not reload again.

Comment: No - The tab needs to be reloaded because it should have received data which it then has to process which then changes the UI. I just don't want it adding to the top of the stack while a previous version is still live lower in the stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(NotifyService.getInstance(), TabContainerActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.setAction("com.test.notify.MESSAGE");
    notificationIntent.putExtra(MessageBean.MESSAGE_ID, messageId);
    notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(notificationIntent);
}
```

I think just using `.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)` to the intent you're using to start the activity again will help you to get the desired result.